# Django ignore get parameters in path

Tags: django, url, path

I have a simple website where I need to parse an url like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/updateproduct?id=1
```

so I wrote the following django path for it:

```
path('updateproduct?id=<int:id>', views.updateProduct, name='updateproduct'),
```

I also tried it like this:

```
path('updateproduct', views.updateProduct, name='updateproduct'),
```

Both of these paths are appended to the `/product/` part of the url like this:

```
path('products/', include('products.urls')),
```

essentially what I want is for django to match any path that starts with `updateproduct` and ignore any get variables (the ? and everything after that). Is this possible?

Comment: Query parameters (the stuff after the `?`)  are always ignored by the router. You can access them in your view via `request.GET`. If you want to match any path that starts with "updateproduct", you could use a regex and ignore the remaining string, e.g. `path_re(r'^updateproduct/.*', views.updateProduct, name='updateproduct'),`

Comment: I think I understand what you mean although I think it's called re_path in django

Answer (score 2, accepted):

django automatically ignores the query when matching the url to a view.

so:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/updateproduct?id=1  &&  http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/updateproduct?id=10&name=value`

will both be handled by the same view.

if you want to access the queries in the view you need to use either

```
request.GET['id']
# or
request.GET.get('id')
```